# Go to specific page in view using node id

Tags: 7, views, paging

I have a view composed of single nodes with a pager. Is there any way to link to a specific page in this view using the node id? I can see that the pager uses a page variable in the url, but that carries no information about the node. I can go to a specific node in the view using contextual filters, but if I don't want to filter the results, I just want to jump to a page in the pager by using the node id. Filtering makes the pager disappear (of course).

Is there a way to pass in a node id to the view, use that information to set the pager to that node, and not lose the pager?

Comment: To clarify, I have a page view with a pager on it. The view is set to show only one full content node at a time. I'd like be able to link to a specific node in that view in such a way that the pager is advanced to that specific node. I do not want to link directly to the node because that would remove the pager.

Comment: Please EDIT your question for clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

You want to link to a node title thats in a view from another page, and not loose your pager ? (correct my summary if thats incorrect) ...

You can do this by using an `ID anchor` when building the link to the node.

If needed, use a Views field to output an html anchor per node title:

- add field Node NID, exclude from View output
- add field Node NID, rewrite HTML as `<a name=[node:nid]>`

Then build a link to your View including the anchor reference.

`$vars['view-scroll-to-node'] = l('some node title', '/your/view/path#'.$nid);`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. It works if the node happens to be on the front page of the view, because then the anchor jumps right to the node on the page. But it doesn't seem to work if the node is not on the first page of the view, because the anchor is not there. It doesn't "jump" to the correct page in the pager that holds that node for me.

Comment: sorry what i'm describing is how to add an anchor to view items. I never told you how to build a random link to a "random node in view paged output page 5".

i dont know how you're trying to build these links into your Views, a custom module, another view block ...

the `&page` is just a query string value. You'd have to find what page chunk the NID would be on and include that in your link parameters. you can do this with ugly SQL. But this isn't a View issue -- its how you choose to build links pointing into your View.